# can we play ffplay videos continuously?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

My requirement is to play ffplay videos as they are joined
I do know we can play the one after the other using

```
ffplay -i 1.mp4 && ffplay -i 2.mp4
```

but here using this method a tab is being opened for each video and I need close to starting playing video some query is there a way to day them directly without this opening and closing tabs

Hope my query is clear
Thank you

I want to play edited videos how we can do with ffplay

```
ffplay -i 1.mp4 -ss 00:00:30.100 -t 00:00:10 -af volume=2.0,atempo=2.0-vf transpose=0,transpose=0,setpts=1/0.5*PTS,fps=30) && ffplay -i 2.mp4 -ss 00:00:30.100 -t 00:00:10 -af volume=2.0,atempo=2.0-vf transpose=0,transpose=0,setpts=1/0.5*PTS,fps=30)
```

Comment: Do they have the same properties as required by the concat demuxer? See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603/ for a list of what these are.

Comment: yes they do have all properties same
and one more thing is there a single command using which I can make a file to set all its properties/ whichever u mentioned on that post? Thank you sir

Comment: @Gyan sir is there anyone command using which I can make any 2 files to the same format and combine them. Even though their resolutions are different do we have a command to make all their fields the same and combine them please let me know sir if their a way I searched for it and found many encodings but when try to test them they say are not found as most of them are outdated please help me with this thank you, sir

Comment: Simple solution is to [use `mpv` with a playlist](https://superuser.com/a/1395885/).

Comment: @llogan sorry i did see abt MPV but I'm not clear in using it and i also want to play edited videos(before exporting them) like how we can do in ffplay i shared a line please if possible convert into MVP command so i can get more clarity thank you

Comment: I answered your question about joined videos. You should only ask 1 question per post (or else nobody will answer), so the "how to play edited videos" should be a new question.

Comment: @llogan got it sir i have added it here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167719/how-to-play-edited-videos-in-mvp" please answer it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `mpv`

`ffplay` is more of a concept or simple tool than a real player. [mpv](https://mpv.io/) is like a "super" `ffplay` and supports playlists:

```
mpv <playlist-filename>
```

`mpv` supports common playlist formats. Or you can just make a simple list with each file on its own line.

Or point it to a directory:

```
mpv /path/to/files
```

See `man mpv`, `mpv --help`, and the online [documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-playlist) for more info on playlists (`--playlist` option).